# how to apply CSS features to Subject line of an Email Template for type HTML(LetterHead)

Tags: email-template

I have a req such as , Email Subject should be in Red color with Bold . 
I have to use only HTML(LetterHead) EmailTemplate .

Comment: You can make email as urgent or important instead.
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008xavIAA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't apply CSS in an Email Subject; it's plain text. This is a limitation of the email protocol ([RFC-822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt)), not a limitation of Salesforce. Remember, HTML was created in 1990, CSS in 1997, and Email in **1982**.

There was no provision for using anything other than plain ASCII until [RFC-1342](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1432.txt), which allowed alternative character sets, such as UTF-8. As such, you can use basic Unicode characters, such as clouds, emojis, and so on, but Unicode does not have any way to specify bold, italic, underlined, or strikethrough characters, nor does it have a way to change the color, font, size, etc.